# InvalidPipeArgument when using Material Autocomplete

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

I'm using the angular material autocomplete to show the list of zip codes from a service.

The error that I'm getting when I type a number is:

```
InvalidPipeArgument: '18224,45429,63341,18976,71730,76008,66058,81505-1432,70360,23301,30081,28622,46815,01754,18405,91722,04553,33584,35078,64747,78746-1603,14850,40390,97207,39703,35213-4211
```

Is this because I have to parse the zip codes?

Thanks for the help!  Adding more to the post to get the looks like your post is mostly code message away....

Here is the code:

names.component.html

```
<form>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input type="text" placeholder="ZipCode" aria-label="ZipCode"
      matInput [formControl]="zipCodeControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
      <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let zipCode of zipCodes | async"
          [value]="zipCode">
          {{zipCode}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

names.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ZipcodeService } from '../zipcode.service';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-names',
  templateUrl: './names.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./names.component.css']
})
export class NamesComponent implements OnInit {
  zipCodeControl = new FormControl();
  zipCodes: string[];
  filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;

  constructor(private zipCodeService: ZipcodeService) { 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.zipCodeService
        .getZipCodes()
        .subscribe(data => {this.zipCodes = data;});

    this.filteredOptions = this.zipCodeControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(value => this._filter(value))
      );
  }

  private _filter(value: string): string[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

    return this.zipCodes.filter(zipCode => zipCode.toLowerCase()
    .includes(filterValue));
  }



}
```

zipcode.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

export interface IZipCodeService {
  getZipCodes(): Observable<string[]>
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ZipcodeService implements IZipCodeService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getZipCodes(): Observable<string[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<string[]>(environment.apiUrl + 'api/zipcode')
               .pipe(map(data => data));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this has been around for some time, but since I had the same problem today and I managed to solve it I will post the solution.

As mentioned above, async needs an observable. The thing here is that your *ngFor should iterate filteredOptions and not the zipCodes, since the zipCodes will be returned by your _filter method.

In other words, the html template should be like this in order for the autocomplete to work:

```
<form>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input type="text" placeholder="ZipCode" aria-label="ZipCode"
      matInput [formControl]="zipCodeControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
      <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async"
          [value]="option">
          {{option}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

You can read more about it in the official documentation: https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview

Answer (score -1):

`zipCodes` is a `string[]` and `async` pipe only accepts an `Observable` or a `Promise` value as an input. Hence the error.

Get rid of the `async` pipe from the template.

Something like this:

```
<form>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input type="text" placeholder="ZipCode" aria-label="ZipCode"
      matInput [formControl]="zipCodeControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
      <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let zipCode of zipCodes"
          [value]="zipCode">
          {{zipCode}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Comment: The zip codes show after I made the change you suggested, but it doesn't start filtering the numbers as I start typing the numbers.  Is that because I took the async out?

Comment: Same problem here. Anything on this?